# Update Autowired Properies on every Request

Tags: spring, scope, autowired

i've some Session-Scoped beans which Autowire some Request scoped beans. But to the Request scoped beans are not updated on every request, so the Session-Scoped beans are accessing old Instances of the Request-Scoped beans. Is there a way to update there References auotmatically?

```
@Controller("requestscoped")
@Scope("request")
public class Requestscoped {
}

@Controller("sessionscoped")
@Scope("session")
public class Sessionscoped {
    @Autowired
    Requestscoped bean;
}
```

At the first Request "sessionscoped" gets a fresh Instance, but on the Second request the "Bean" property holds the "requestscoped" from the first request